# Logic for parsing XML file with different tag names within the same hirearchy using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML file that looks similar to format below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <paragraph>val1</paragraph>
   <list>aa1</list>
   <list>aa2</list>
   <list>aa3</list>
   <paragraph>val2</paragraph>
   <list>bb1</list>
   <paragraph>val3</paragraph>
   <list>cc1</list>
   <list>cc2</list>
</section>
```

I am trying to write a PHP code to print the results like following,

```
val1 - aa1
val1 - aa2
val1 - aa3
val2 - bb1
val3 - cc1
val3 - cc2
```

I have problem with deriving the logic. Could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Your xml has a very bad construction logic, can you do some change on it or you have to use this format ? Did you try something ?

Comment: This is the format I have to use and I cannot change the XML structure...

Comment: You get xml from a file or from a string ?

Comment: I get it from a file

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to change xml structure and use SimpleXml Class. 
But this code will do what you want : https://eval.in/672099

```
$string =<<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <paragraph>val1</paragraph>
   <list>aa1</list>
   <list>aa2</list>
   <list>aa3</list>
   <paragraph>val2</paragraph>
   <list>bb1</list>
   <paragraph>val3</paragraph>
   <list>cc1</list>
   <list>cc2</list>
</section>
EOF;

 preg_match('#<section>(.*)<\/section>#s', $string, $section);
 preg_match_all('#<paragraph>(.*)<\/paragraph>#sU', $section[1], $paragraph);
 $lists = preg_split('#<paragraph>(.*)<\/paragraph>#sU', $section[1]);

 foreach($paragraph[1] as $key => $p){
    $list = null;
    preg_match_all('#<list>(.*)<\/list>#sU', $lists[$key+1], $list);
    foreach($list[1] as $l){
      echo $p . ' - ' . $l . PHP_EOL;
    }
 }
```

Output :

```
val1 - aa1
val1 - aa2
val1 - aa3
val2 - bb1
val3 - cc1
val3 - cc2
```

**EDIT**

With a file you can replace $string assignation by

```
$string = file_get_contents("path/to/file.xml");
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use regex after explode, say $x is the xml.

```
$y = explode('<paragraph>', $x);

unset($y[0]);
foreach($y as $z)
{
    preg_match_all('/(.*)<\/paragraph>?/', $z, $matches);
    preg_match_all('/<list>(.*)<\/list>/', $z, $matches2);
}
```

$matches[1] and $matches2[1] are what you want.